# Why does Volley use so many threads on my app?

Tags: android, android-volley

[image: A sample listing of several Volley threads during normal-heavy app operation]

I've been looking through a thread dump of an application I'm working on where we use Volley. I've looked at half of the threads, and so far I've found 40 volley threads, mostly NetworkDispatcher but some CacheDispatcher. We use volley in one activity. In OnCreate:

```
volleyQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

And then,

```
ImageRequest s3ImageRequest = new ImageRequest(
        decryptedImageURL.toString(),
        new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Bitmap bitmap) {
                imageBitmap = bitmap;
                loadingImage = false;
            }
        },
        0, // max width
        0, // max height
        null, // decode configuration
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Rlog.e(TAG, "Riff Playback: could not load image through Volley: " + decryptedImageURL);
                volleyError.printStackTrace();
                abortPlayback();
            }
        }
);
s3ImageRequest.setTag(TAG);
volleyQueue.add(s3ImageRequest);
```

What could be causing such an egregious proliferation of background threads?

Comment: I wouldn't really call this an "egregious proliferation of background threads"... all of the threads are blocking on `Object#wait()` in the screenshot you posted so they are probably just part of a thread pool or something...

Answer (score 2):

One of the major design decisions behind Volley is performing many image loading (or really any small http requests) simultaneously. Volley works by creating many threads dedicated to loading images so that you can perform these simultaneous network calls.

Fun fact, Volley actually is called Volley, because it was named after a collection of arrows all raining down on a surface at the same time. Try and think of the network requests as arrows and it may make it a little clearer.

You can check out more about [Volley](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhv8l9F44qo) in this awesome Google I/O video that features the creator of Volley, Ficus Kirkpatrick, talking about his invention.

Comment: Just clarifying, so, having 40+ background threads is normal? Because I've been reading up and it seems like a very small subset of people suggest to keep a global application-wide volley queue. Would that kind of optimization help?